# Icon change on Jquery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm trying to add an icon change when I click on a section, I added the functionality when all the accordion is opened or closed but I'm not able to add this functionality when I just open one section without changing all other section icons.

```
This is the code:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t2beth2L/2/

Comment: You change the text of the whole class that's why plus changes everywhere. All you gotta do is to add unique id to each of them and handle them separately by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fiddle, **contentAreas** is a list of all of the content areas. So binding events like this

```
contentAreas.on({
    hide: ...,
    show: ...
});
```

means that when you click Show/Hide All, the hide/show functions will execute once for each content area.

Since you know whether the area is being hidden or shown (based on the event), simply set the appropriate icon (- or +) for that section.

It doesn't really matter if the user does this via the Show/Hide All button, or by clicking on an individual header.

```js
var headers = $('#accordion .accordion-header');
var contentAreas = $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content ').hide();
var expandLink = $('.accordion-expand-all');


headers.click(function() {
  var panel = $(this).next();
  var isOpen = panel.is(':visible');

  panel[isOpen ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']()
    .trigger(isOpen ? 'hide' : 'show');

  return false;
});


expandLink.click(function() {
  var isAllOpen = $(this).data('isAllOpen');

  contentAreas[isAllOpen ? 'hide' : 'show']()
    .trigger(isAllOpen ? 'hide' : 'show');
});


contentAreas.on({
  show: function($event) {
    var isAllOpen = !contentAreas.is(':hidden');
    if (isAllOpen) {
      expandLink.text('Close All')
        .data('isAllOpen', true);
    }
    
    // this content area is now being shown, so show the 'hide' icon
    setIcon($event.currentTarget, '-');
  },

  hide: function($event) {
    var isAllOpen = !contentAreas.is(':hidden');
    if (!isAllOpen) {
      expandLink.text('Open All')
        .data('isAllOpen', false);
    }

    // this content area is now being shown, so show the 'show' icon
    setIcon($event.currentTarget, '+');
  }
});

function setIcon(sectionEl, sectionIcon) {
  var currentSection = $(sectionEl);
  var currentSectionHeader = currentSection.prev();
  currentSectionHeader.find('.plusminus').text(sectionIcon);
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}



.accordion-expand-holder {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container-accordion{
    padding-top: 8em;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
    
.ui-accordion-content > p {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

#accordion > h2 {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.plusminus {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-accordion">
  <p class="accordion-expand-holder">
    <a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#">Open All</a>
  </p>
  <div id="accordion">

    <h2 class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header">Title 1 <span class="plusminus">+</span></h2>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2 class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header">Title 2 <span class="plusminus">+</span></h2>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2 class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header">Title 3 <span class="plusminus">+</span></h2>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Bags! You made my day, works perfect!!